# How to print the active page in PDF with Geb?

Tags: pdf, printing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geb

Is it possible to print the currently active page in PDF with Geb? I want to print a page in PDF to check the "print view" / layout. How can I realize this?

The `Book of Geb` does not describe how a menu entry of the browser can be accessed (such as "Print page" in Firefox) and the "[Browser methods](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.2/binding.html#browser_methods__properties)" only include `download*` methods but no `print*` methods.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this?